# Adding a rating button in Alert Controller Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there anyway I can add button in my ionic alert controller? Im creating a rate me for a place. User will be able to add a text, and a star rating.

I've used this star rating for my application: https://github.com/andrucz/ionic2-rating

```
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Rate Venue',
  inputs: [{
      name: 'review',
      placeholder: 'Review'
    },
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text:`<rating [(ngModel)]= 'rate'         
       readOnly = 'false'        
       max = 5        
       emptyStarIconName =star-outline       
       halfStarIconName = star-half       
       starIconName = star        
       nullable = false       
      (ngModelChange) = onModelChange($event)>
      </rating>`,

    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Save',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Saved clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
});
prompt.present();
```

Comment: Why do you need a buttton? Can't you submit the rating once you choose the star rating the very first time?

Comment: I want the star button to be inside a alert controller

Comment: No I mean why you need a button to save your rating? Why don't you dynamically catch the rating on clicking the star at the moment?\

Comment: I had a similar requirement. I have added my solution in [Rating alert/feature using Ionic alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267705/rating-alert-feature-using-ionic-alert/50267706#50267706)